# How to process again events in Azure Event Hubs with Stream Analytics job?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I have set up an event hub which I store some events and an Azure Stream Analytics Job which processes them and outputs into a blob container. Given that the message retention in the hub is set to 5 days, how can I process these events again, i.e. to output them into a database?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-archive-eventhub-capture

Answer (score 0):

OK, for a simple scenario you just have to set the `job output start time` to an earlier time, as in:

```
az stream-analytics job start
--resource-group MyResourceGroup
--name MyJobName
--output-start-mode CustomTime
--output-start-time 2020-12-04T08:30:00Z
```